# My local JSON serialization/parsing is not working?

Tags: ios, json, swift, local

Video showing the problem at runtime: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INVTDEJ8ZqY

I am having a lot of trouble correctly parsing the JSON from a local JSON file, storing it into an array and then displaying it in my view.

My app doesn't crash. My 4 buttons and 1 label simply do not change values. They just get those sample values I added in there "Question 1", "Question 2", etc...

How do I get it to display the values from my JSON file ? It looks like [this](http://numbersapi.com/1..100/trivia?fragment&json)

```
/* Question label storyboard outlet */
@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!

// Answer button storyboard outlets
@IBOutlet weak var topLeftButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var topRightButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomLeftButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomRightButton: UIButton!

/* Questions Set */
var questionObjects = NSMutableOrderedSet(capacity: 100)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getQuestionsFromJSONFile()
    displayQuestion(0, jsonObjectsSet: questionObjects)

    let string = "some Random Question"
    questionLabel.text = string.capitalizeFirstCharacter
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func getQuestionsFromJSONFile() {
    var questionsJSONData: NSData? = nil
    do {
        let pathToQuestionsJSONFile = try NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Trivia_100-199", ofType: "json")
        do {
            questionsJSONData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: pathToQuestionsJSONFile!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
            let questionsJSONContent = JSON(data: questionsJSONData!)
            if let object : [String:[String:AnyObject]] = questionsJSONContent.object as? [String:[String:AnyObject]] {
                parseJSONContentIntoObjects(object)
            }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        /*
        if let questionsJSONContent = JSON(data: questionsJSONData!) as? [String: [String : AnyObject]] {
            parseJSONContentIntoObjects(questionsJSONContent) // PSE: Potential Source of Error
        }
        */
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        print(error.localizedFailureReason)
        print(error.localizedRecoveryOptions)
        print(error.localizedRecoverySuggestion)
    }
}

func parseJSONContentIntoObjects(jsonData: [String: [String : AnyObject]]) {
    var questionHasAProperAnswer = false // indicator to determine if a proper answer was provided by the API for this specific question
    let jsonObjects = NSMutableOrderedSet(capacity: 100)
    for (questionAnswer,questionPropertiesSubJson):(String,[String:AnyObject]) in jsonData {
        if let questionObject = Question(questionObjectSubJson: questionPropertiesSubJson) as? Question { // All parsing code is in the model file (Question.swift)
        if let answerText = questionObject.questionAnswer as? String {
            let questionExclusionKeywords = ["the Earth probably", "boring", "uninteresting", "unremarkable", "we do not know", "nothing", "remarkable", "a number for which", "missing a fact"]
            for questionExclusionKeyword in (questionExclusionKeywords as? [String])! {
                questionHasAProperAnswer = !answerText.containsString(questionExclusionKeyword)
             /*
                if questionHasAProperAnswer {
                    jsonObjects.addObject(questionObject)
                }
            }

            if answerText.containsAny(questionExclusionKeywords) {
                jsonObjects.addObject(questionObject)
                }
            */
            jsonObjects.addObject(questionObject)
            }
        }
    }
    questionObjects = jsonObjects
    if questionObjects.count == 0 {
        let fillerObject = Question(questionText: "Some question", questionAnswer: 1234, questionFalseAnswer1: "333", questionFalseAnswer2: "444", questionFalseAnswer3: "555")
        questionObjects.addObject(fillerObject)
    }

}
}

func displayQuestion(questionIndex: Int, jsonObjectsSet: NSMutableOrderedSet) {
    if let specificQuestionObject = jsonObjectsSet.objectAtIndex(questionIndex) as? Question {
        if let questionText = specificQuestionObject.questionText {
            questionLabel.text = questionText
        }
        if let questionAnswer = specificQuestionObject.questionAnswer as? String {
            let capitalizedQuestionAnswer = questionAnswer.capitalizeFirstCharacter
            topLeftButton.titleLabel?.text = capitalizedQuestionAnswer
        }
        bottomLeftButton.titleLabel?.text = "Some false answer"
        topRightButton.titleLabel?.text = "Some other false answer"
        bottomRightButton.titleLabel?.text = "Another random false answer"
    }
}
```

Comment: First resolve all type casting warnings seen in the video.

Answer (score 2):

For buttons, you should use `setTitle(forState:)`. For example:

```
button.setTitle("foo", forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: Thank you for that, it made part of my code work, but the hard part (local parsing) still is not working properly :( The only part that works now, thanks to your code, is the placeholder text for the three buttons in "displayQuestion". Do you think you could help me with that local parsing part ? It's really been keeping me from making progress these past few days.

Comment: For the local parsing stuff, all I see is JSON with questions, but I don't see any answers. How can `Question` produce `questionAnswer`. In terms of diagnosing problems like this in general, though, it's just a laborious single-stepping through the code, line by line, and just figure out at precisely which line it's failing. Until you do that, we're just guessing. There are a ton of nit-picky little issues in the code you've provided, but because you've buried some of the parsing in `Question`, we can't advise you on the root of the issue (other than absence of answers in JSON).